# Node.js is not sending cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, requestjs

I use node.js to collect messages and notifications from 10 different websites and then I send them to my email account (something like daily report). I have done this job for 5 different websites, but now I'm having issues with Amazon.

What I need to do with Amazon is to login using my credentials, and then to parse some data.

After several implementations, and different approaches, I finally realized that amazon refuses me to login because cookies are not supported, but that is not true, cookies are supported in my node.js script I'm using cookies to login to other websites.

As proof I opened Amazon login page using node.js and then I saved response to .html file. When I open this saved html file I can see that Amazon requires me to enable cookies. Here is screen shot: 
[image: Amazaon cookies]

Here is my node.js cript:

```
var request = require("request");
request = request.defaults({jar: true});//Send cookies on every subsequent requests. This is really important
var requestHeaders = new DRequestHeaders();
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
var user = new DUser('test','test');

//First open start site: http://amazon.com
request.get({headers:requestHeaders.getHeaders(), uri: user.getUrl('startSeite'), followRedirect: true, maxRedirects: 10,}, function(err, res, body) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('GET request failed here is error');
        console.log(res);
    }

    //Get login link
    $=cheerio.load(body);
    user.setNewUrl('login',$('#nav-link-yourAccount').attr('href'));
    console.log(user.getUrl('login'));
    //Go to the login link
    request.get({headers:requestHeaders.getHeaders(), uri: user.getUrl('login'), followRedirect: true, maxRedirects: 10,}, function(err, res, body) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('GET request failed here is error');
            console.log(res);
        }

        //Now we are at login page. We want to prepare for form submittion
        //Get hidden input fields
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var inputsFields = $('#ap_signin_form :input');//Get all inputs
        user.setNewUrl('form-submit',$('#ap_signin_form').attr('action'));
        var formSubmitData = {};
        inputsFields.each(function() {
            formSubmitData[this.attribs['name']]=this.attribs['value'];//Get attribute name and value
        });
        //Set username and password, and now everything is ready for form submission
        formSubmitData['email'] = user.getUsername();
        formSubmitData['password'] = user.getPassword();

        //This is just for demonstration. I save response from amazon so I can clearly see the message that cookies are not supported
        fs.writeFile("amazon.html", body, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        });

    });
});
```

When I print response object, and find original request, I can clearly seethat node.js did send some cookies, but why Amazon is refusing them?

```
      GET /ap/signin/278-4773600-2469922?_encoding=in HTTP/1.1\r\n
        Accept: text/html\r\n
        Accept-Language: en-US\r\n
        Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n
        Connection: keep-alive\r\n
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36\r\n
        Cookie: x-wl-uid=1VIRmGEpmmFvZeJXhczJzp7Uv4qmAA6yIt40QrU9OMMLth6j0vSM0j7lKYDYo=; session-id-time=2082751l; session-id=944-4770-24922\r\n
        content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
host: www.amazon.com
```

Comment: You can check up on your, excuse the pun, `cookieJar` whether the required cookies are saved. Or that Amazon is running a JS file that checks up on whether browser cookies are enabled and throws the error (because you're relying on a script to parse the page).

Comment: If Amazon runs JS file which checks COOKIES what can help?

Comment: At that point, I'd try accessing the page on a browser with JS disabled. This way you confirm that it's the JS that's checking for cookies.

Comment: Ja when I disable cookies in browser I get the same message. How can I resolve this with node.js is there anyway I can do it?

Comment: What about when you disable JavaScript?

Comment: When I disable cookies in Chrome, I get the same message. I also found a JS code on amazon website which checks if cookies are enabled, but how to avoid that with node.js?

Comment: Don't disable cookies please but instead disable JS. You have to ensure 100% that it's JS causing that. It will be strange for a company of it's size to not allow users to navigate their site without JS. You can do this by going into Chrome dev tools (press F12) and go to the top right corner and click on the Settings, then under the "General" settings, click on "Disable JavaScript". Then reload the page and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Yep, it is javascript. When I disable javascript, I can not login.

Comment: I assume they check for something like `document.cookie` and throw an error if it returns false. You'll have to read their JS to understand what functionality it plays/where it throws errors. At the end of the day, it's using a backend that keeps the state and JS can't do that for you. With that in mind, you can always find a way to log in but it might not be worth it.